# Textview cannot be cast to android.widget.listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I believe to have the textview, but it cannot be cast to listview error in the following code below:
Essentially I am trying to populate information from Parse into a textfield. This I believe is the part of the code that is problematic.

here it throws a "textview cannot be cast to android.widget.listview"

```
public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistactivityname, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivityname.size(); i++) {
             mUserActivityNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistactivityname);
            mUserActivityNameRetrieved.setText(userlistactivityname.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());
        }

    } else {
        //else..
    }
}
```

Below is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/left_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistheadline"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:textAlignment="center" >
    </ListView>

    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistheadline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Activity Name"
        android:textColor="#d2f2a2"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMatchConfirm"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="#ADD8E6"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userlistname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical|none"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical|none"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" >
    </TextView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: i don't see where you try to cast a textview to listview... please provide the correct piece of code...

Comment: What kind of object is mUserActivityNameRetrieved?

Please provide your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

you have used the ID "userlistactivityname" more than once, e.g. you define a textview and give it the id userlistactivityname, but later you also have a button with the same id "userlistactivityname"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userlistactivityname"
    ...
    android:divider="@null" >
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMatchConfirm"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userlistactivityname"
    ...
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

and maybe you even have another widget defined as "userlistactivityname". 
Search all your layouts for "userlistactivityname" and make sure that the id is unique!

Answer (score 0):

When you want a view to be below / above / leftOf another view, you reference the view using the code

```
@id/view_id
```

when you want to add a new id to the Android R file, you use the code

```
@+id/new_view_id
```

if you use @+id/ all the time, you can create problems in your R file. Try changing all references in your code to make it cleaner, and only using @+id/ when specifying android:id

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMatchConfirm"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/userlistactivityname"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="#ADD8E6"
    android:text="Confirm"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```